# Facebook share button with custom title and message etc

Tags: facebook, share-button

I have integrated a Facebook Share button in my website. The one that you can generate here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

But how can I tell it what title, message to show and what url to redirect to? It now all "tries" to automatically resolve this from the web page.

It uses the right title from the `<title>` tag. But the meta `description` tag is not working. And I also have no clue how to set a custom URL and image.

All I have now is:

This right below the opening of the `body` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=19158xxxxxxxxx&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And this on a product detail page:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

How can I customize everything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `og:title` and `og:description` meta tags as per http://ogp.me.

Those are the tags that Facebook will initially scrape for the share info.

Alternatively you can use the javascript sdk and specify the title, URL, description, etc manually as described [in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui)

Comment: I tried to add `<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />` but it didn't change the title in the popup. Even `og:description` didnt change anything. Any idea why? Both tags where there in the `head` when I looked at the web page source.

Comment: Use the open graph debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Facebook caches the data, this tool will clear that cache